# Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm not able to attach files in outlook online clients

Tags: javascript, api, office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are using Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm api for creating compose form in that we are adding attachments parameter with **type** set to **file**. But in this scenario, Outlook is not able to attach file in compose form of **outlook online clients** whereas the same scenario is working in windows Outlook 2016 and outlook for Mac.

We are referring to the example below, given in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox#displaynewmessageformparameters

```
Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm(
  {
    // Copy the To line from current item.
    toRecipients: Office.context.mailbox.item.to,
    ccRecipients: ['sam@contoso.com'],
    subject: 'Outlook add-ins are cool!',
    htmlBody: 'Hello <b>World</b>!<br/>',
    attachments: [
      {
        type: 'file',
        name: 'image.png',
        url: 'http://contoso.com/image.png',
        isInline: false
      }
    ]
  });
```

After using this api outlook creates new compose form with attachment (Note: I can't view or download that attachment, it is attached as label only). [Refer to this image for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNpUx.png)

And, that attachment **vanishes** after some time and outlook gives an error in notification bar i.e. **The following file couldn't be attached: image.png. Please try again later**.[Refer this image for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyG1u.png)

Also the same api is able to attach items in outlook online clients when attachments.**type** is set to **item** as follows:

```
attachments: [
      {
        type: 'item',
        name: 'filename.png',
        itemId: ewsId
      }
    ]
```

Can anyone suggest why is this happening and any workaround for the above issue?

Comment: Vinaysheel, looks like the url you are using doesn't exist. I'm seeing consistent behavior on both Desktop Outlook and Outlook Web App.

https://ibb.co/QHhGNYL

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. Url which is given above is just an reference url and I'm not using that, I am using a valid url and api is able to attach file in outlook 2016 for windows and outlook for mac but not in online clients(browsers). Since it is an production url I can't post it here, but I checked again and confirmed it is a valid url.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue. If you can provide the URL of a different which can reproduce the issue, it will help us debug the issue.

Comment: It was an server configuration error due to which it was blocking request for Outlook online clients. Now, Api is working fine in all clients